# Zalenium Grid: How to set timeouts, maxInstances and maxSessions?

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, grid, zalenium

After running continuously for hours I am getting the following error

`X request waiting for slots to be free`

```
22:39:19 [main] ERROR net.thucydides.core.steps.ConsoleLoggingListener - Could not instantiate new WebDriver instance of type class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver (Error forwarding the new session Request timed out waiting for a node to become available.
```

After searching this error on forums I found that I need set maxInstances, maxSessions, and timeouts (suggest if this is not the solution).

So, how can I set these 3 properties with this command:

```
docker run --rm -ti --name zalenium -p 4444:4444 \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    -v /tmp/videos:/home/seluser/videos \
    --privileged dosel/zalenium start
```

Answer (score 0):

u can increase the instances and nodes using below command

docker run -d -ti --restart always --name zalenium -p 4444:4444 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /c/Zalenium/videos:/home/seluser/videos dosel/zalenium start --maxDockerSeleniumContainers 30 --desiredContainers 6 --maxTestSessions 2

Answer (score 0):

By default, Zalenium allows a test to be idle up to 90 seconds. After that elapsed time, the session will be terminated, the node will be shutdown and the recorded video will be saved (if video recording is enabled). This prevents a test to run indefinitely after something went wrong. If you need to have a longer idle timeout, just set an idleTimeout capability in your test. Example code in Java for the capability (it sets the idleTimeout to 150 seconds):

```
DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
desiredCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, BrowserType.FIREFOX);
desiredCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, Platform.LINUX);
desiredCapabilities.setCapability("idleTimeout", 150);
```

For more: https://opensource.zalando.com/zalenium/#usage